# Return a shared pointer from a function vs Capturing a shared pointer in a Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, smart-pointers, rvalue, dangling-pointer

I am constructing a shared pointer in a `function_1` and giving it as a capture to a lambda.

I think this is an issue, could you please confirm if this safe or I am right and I shoudn't be doing this?

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using Op = std::function<double(std::size_t)>;
struct A
{
    std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<double>> function_1() const
    {
        const std::vector<double> v = {1.0, 2.0};
        auto pVec = std::make_shared<const std::vector<double>>(v);
        return pVec;
    };
};

struct B
{
    B() { m_a = A(); };
    
    void populate_op(Op& op) const
    {
        std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<double>> pVec = m_a.function_1();
        op = [pVec](const std::size_t index) -> double
        {
            return pVec->at(index);
        };
    }
    
    void run()
    {
        m_futures.resize(2u);
        Op op0;
        populate_op(op0);
        m_futures[0u] = std::async(std::launch::async, op0, 0u);
        
        Op op1;
        populate_op(op1);
        m_futures[1u] = std::async(std::launch::async, op1, 1u);
        
        const double res0 = m_futures[0u].get();
        const double res1 = m_futures[1u].get();
        
        std::cout << res0 + res1 << std::endl;
        //clean futures
    }
    
private:
    A m_a;
    mutable std::vector<std::future<double>> m_futures;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Wont the `v` be destructed as it's a local variable and I will end up with a moved shared pointer pointing to a destructed object and hence capturing the latter in the lambda?

Comment: Likely the shared pointer is copying the object and I shouldn't have issues? What if the vector itself is of pointers to objects/instances instead of just of doubles? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr` is a smart pointer to dynamically-allocated storage holding the value that is shared. `make_shared` allocates that storage and constructs the value by passing the passed arguments to the constructor of the type. In this case, since you are constructing a `vector` by passing a `vector`, it calls `vector`'s copy constructor. The `vector` in the shared storage and the `vector` that you passed are completely separate objects; it's just that one was constructed by copying the other.

So yes, `v` will be destructed when `v`'s scope ends. This has nothing to do with the separate `vector` in the shared storage that was dynamically allocated. That `vector` will be destructed (and the memory freed) when the reference counting determines that there are no more `shared_ptr`'s pointing to that shared storage.